# $f$ in $L^2$ space imply $\sup{f} > 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis

If $f(k)\leq K$ a.e in $\Omega$.

$|\Omega|= +\infty$ ,$K$ is constant,and $f \in L^2$.

Why we can say $K\geq 0$? (from Haim Brezis functional analysis sobolev space and partial differential equations, P308, chapter 9.)

Comment: It is not true for example f=-1 on (0,1) is such that $f\leq -1$ but $k=-1\leq 0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
f(x)\le K < 0, \mu(\Omega) = \infty\implies
\infty = \int_\Omega K^2\,d\mu\le\int_\Omega f^2\,d\mu.
$$

Comment: oh, i see, but if $|\Omega|= +\infty$

Comment: thank you, but i think the proof is not rigorous.if suppose $f\leq 0 \leq K,$ also can get the right result.?

Comment: @Ben, with $f\le 0\le K$ we **can't** deduce $f^2\le K^2$ (counterexample: $-2\le0 \le 1$ but $(-2)^2\not\le 1^2)$.

Comment: get it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @Ben, then you can accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

$L^2(\mathbb{R})$ contains unbounded functions.

Consider the piecewise constant function $f$ defined as follows. 
For any positive integer $n$ put
$f(x) = n$ for $x\in(n, n+1/n^4)$, elsewhere we set $f(x)=0$.

Now 
$$\int|f(x)|^2\,dx =\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{n^2}{n^4}=..$$